# Pre order system in Strip API

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using a strip payment gateway in our website as per customer demand "pre order system" integrate in website for example after place a order payment has been saved in strip account & when website administrator change the order status "delivered" than payment deduct.
Is it possible in strip payment API.if yes please provide a documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such an option and it is called `auth & capture`. See bellow -

https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture

Briefly, when you are creating a new charge, you pass `capture => false` param so stripe is just reserving the specified amount.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

Comment: find this code. $ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve({CHARGE_ID});
$ch->capture(); how to get "CHARGE_ID" id ?

Comment: can i use $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(amount=>12)); first than use retrieve function ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the create function to create a charge and get the charge_id first. Then you can execute the capture using that id.

Comment: Any idea of how to update the order amount in strip payment when order is uncaptured condition please answer me.:(

Answer (score 0):

If there is less than 7 days between the moment the order is created and the moment you want to actually charge the card, then you can use the [auth & capture](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture) flow as Tosho explained.

Otherwise, you can [create a customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) to save card information, and use it later to actually [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge). This is explained in [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later). Note that in this case, you have no guarantee that the charge will go through successfully.